# Process Captcha for OCR

Tags: image, image-processing

Trying to pre process this image for OCR. And I am not able to figure out how to get rid of that bump in the centre of the captcha.

Original Captcha - [Captcha](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfwYn.png)

This is as far I can get but still this isn't good enough.

Processed Captcha - [CaptchaProcessed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IrtI.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a captcha you should solve with a neuronal network like this:

1. Write something to gernerate this kind of captcha by yourself (with bounding boxes) aka: training data
2. Train a neuronal network on your training data
3. profit

See how its done for a different captcha typ here: https://github.com/cracker0dks/CaptchaSolver/blob/master/docs/howToSolveNew6DigitCaptchasWalkthrough.md